# Get 2 characters from file name in powershell

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a PowerShell script, that changes the last file encoding in the folder, then copies it to another folder, however, I need to rename the output file name using 2 characters from the input file name.
Please help me)

Here is the script

```
    $source=Get-ChildItem "C:\StatementAMImport\NewEmails_*.xml" | select  -Last 1
    $File = Get-Content $source
    $Utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    $Out = 'D:\UTF8\file.zpm'
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($Out, $File, $Utf8)
```

Input file full name example  `NewEmails_20210805_180345`
I need to get the day, which is 05 in my example

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so `$source` is the file object

with that you can get its name

```
$sourceFileName = $source.BaseName
```

to get the day (which is at a fixed position) you can use the `SubString()` Method

```
$outputDay = $sourceFileName.Substring(16,2)
```

now `$outputDay` contains '05'

Comment: $source=Get-ChildItem "C:\StatementAMImport\NewEmails_*.xml" | select  -Last 1
$File = Get-Content $source
$Utf8 = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
$sourceFileName = $source.base
$outputDay = $sourceFileName.Substring(16,2)
$Out = ("D:\UTF8\" + $outputDay)
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($Out, $File, $Utf8)

geting that error

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

Comment: my bad - i updated the script. the command fixed was `$sourceFileName = $source.BaseName` - i was missing 'name'. sorry about that

Comment: ps: for file naming i use the following: `$Out = 'D:\UTF8\{0}.zpm' -f $outputDay` that way the `{0}` gets replaced by the variable after `-f`